# Relation between factors and their sum on RSA

Tags: rsa, prime-numbers

In RSA and other crypto based on prime factors. If I would know the sum of $p+q$, would it reveal any more information than just knowing $p\cdot q$?

Edit: I do not know either $p$ or $q$. The question relates to the fact that if I know the sum and the multiplication, can I find the factors $p$ and $q$ faster compared to when I don't know the sum?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, are you asking about the case where you _just_ know $p+q$ (but not $p\cdot q$) or where you know $p+q$ _and_ $p\cdot q$?

Comment: I guess you are asking the case where you knoe both $m=pq$ and $a=p+q$. In this case, you can find $p$ and $q$ by solving the quadratic equation $x^2-ax+m=0$.

Comment: You can also directly compute $d = e^{-1} \pmod{n-(p+q)+1)}$.

Comment: yes I know p+q and p*q (but I don't know P or Q. Given that they are big int (>1024 bit) does knowing the sum make it easier to find P&Q?

Comment: What is capital $P$ and $Q$?

Comment: I am sorry they are the same as lowercase, I just know the sum of p and q and the multiplication of p*q.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $n = p \cdot q $ be product of distinct primes $p$ and $q$, of arbitrary size as in the RSA setup.

The RSA public key $(n,e)$ contains both the modulus and the public exponent, so **we assume both are known**.

Let $b = p +q$. If $b$ is also known, then we can form a [quadratic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation) as

$$ f(x) = x^2 - b x + n \label{1}\tag{1}$$ by using the following identity:

$$(x-p)(x-q) = x^2 - (p+q) x + (p\cdot q).$$

The solution of the quadratic equation (\ref{1}) is that $p$ and $q$ and can be found by the second-degree formulas using this equation:

$$p,q =  \frac{ b \pm \Delta}{2}$$ where the discriminant $\Delta = \sqrt{b^2 - 4n}.$

It is also possible to directly find the private exponent too! Observe that:

$$\varphi(n) = (p-1)(q-1) = pq - p -q +1 = pq - (p +q) +1 = n - b + 1.$$

Since $e \cdot d \equiv 1 \bmod \varphi(n)$, you can solve for $d$ without computing $p$ and $q$, though those are also cheap to compute if you would still like to use them.

---

**Example:**

Let $m = 35$ and $b = 12$. We thus need to solve $x^2 - 12x + 35$, which gives us:

$$\Delta = \sqrt{12^2 - 4 \cdot 35} = \sqrt{144 - 140} = \sqrt{4} =2. $$

As a result:

$$p = \frac{12 + 2}{2} = 7 \text { and }  q = \frac{12 - 2}{2} = 5.$$

Comment: Please see my edit but: does this mean, that revealing the sum will expose $p$ and $q$?

Comment: That is exactly what you need, call their sum $b$ and multiple as $n$ the modulus then it works,

Comment: Sorry I might not understand how exactly. Given p=5 and q=7, m=35 and s=12. How do I find 5 & 7 from f(35, 12) (other than brute force)?

Comment: Ok I got it! Thnx!

Comment: @ovanwijk added the example.